# .torrent or .exe file?? confused!

Tags: executable, bittorrent, transmission

I am new with ubuntu here.

I have installed kubuntu on my pc.

I want to download a torrent file, I have done that before and also have used transmission. But I recently downloaded 'wine' a software that helps in running windows files on ubuntu. Now when I try to download a torrent file it won't let me. I want a plain torrent file to run on transmission.

[image: this is what it shows me >.<]

Comment: You clicked on the wrong link.

Comment: no i didn't... I tried the pirate bay as well. shows me the exact same thing...

Comment: Presumably you clicked on that big "Download" button?

Comment: nope... I clicked on the one with a crown.
not once, not twice but around 50 times, again n again. shows me the same thing...
can I add an image in the comments? if yes, tell me how so that I can show you...

Comment: this works fine. I was on the wrong site. thanks...
but what about the pirate bay link?? It also showed me the same .exe file.

Comment: Stay away from that site.. http://www.scamadviser.com/is-finaljuyu.com-a-fake-site.html Wellknown junkware site..

Comment: @random I write it as an answer, if you are satisfied then please accept it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are definitely not on the right website there (finaljuyu.com? doensn't sound at all like the website you were trying to reach).

Try to go to [kickass.to](https://kickass.to), search for a torrent (possibily not copyrighted material), press  "Download Torrent" and it will download the right `.torrent` file.

Comment: -1 for linking to an unofficial Ubuntu torrent link, which may contain who knows what. If you do want to link to torrents of Ubuntu, thereare plenty on the Ubuntu sites: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/

Comment: @muru Although the Hash sum of the .iso file doesn't lie, you are definitely right. I modify my answer (and the comment above).